# How to download videos from MathWorks website?

Tags: video, download

There are a lot of free videos on [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/). For example [this](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/tech-talks/controls/?s_tid=hp_mi_techtalks_0913) list. There are also a lot of free Webinars that are open to every one.

I do not have access to internet at all times. I would like to watch some videos offline.

Do you know what is the format of these videos, and how can I download them?

Comment: How can I know if it is a Flash video?

Comment: The videos are hosted by Brightcove Video Cloud and are protected from the normal set of flv downloaders.

Comment: @Ali right click on the video and if you get flash options in the context menu, its flash. I checked one of the videos and it is a flash video

Comment: @Tog, How did you find it out? So, there is no way to download videos from it?

Comment: @Shakehar Yeah, I know that. Some of them are flash videos. But if you click on some of them, you will not anything. Tnx.

Comment: @Ali, right-click on the video, select "About Brightcove PLatform"

Comment: @Tog I can not right click on the videos, but I saw the link for Britghtcove in the page source. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using a Firefox plugin. I personally use [FLV Movies Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flv-movies-downloader/). There may be better plugins and plugins for other browsers, but this is the one I have experience with.

Once you install it, you can go to the page with the videos and then go to *Tools > Download flv > Show detected movies*. Then choose the video from the list (it will probably have a larger file size then the rest of the items) and click *Download file*.

This is the best method I know of for downloading embedded videos on the web.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different plugins and extensions. But, none of them work. They even do not recognize the videos.

Comment: Could you try linking to the page with the videos one more time? The link you provided does not work.

Comment: Strange, I added a new list of videos.

Comment: @Ali Dude, try your own link see it's broken and correct it

Comment: I just tried it and it is working!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Internet download Manger(IDM)
this videos have .flv format.
The best software for download all videos